# iOS: How do you make two UIViews auto fill space?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am trying to programmatically make two views share width of a parent view.  I have tried either using an init for the subviews and an initWithFrame, but in either case, I can't get the stretching to work correctly.  In the example below, I am expecting to see a red window spanning half of the width of the screen and a green window filling the other half.  What am I missing?

```
self.view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.window.frame];
self.left = [[UIView alloc] init];
self.right = [[UIView alloc] init];

[self.left setAutoresizingMask:(UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight)];
[self.right setAutoresizingMask:(UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight)];

[self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
[self.left setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
[self.right setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];

[self.left setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleToFill];
[self.right setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleToFill];


[self.view addSubview:self.left];
[self.view addSubview:self.right];
[self.view setAutoresizesSubviews:YES];

[self.window addSubview:self.view];
```

Thanks!

Comment: What do you see when you run that code?

Comment: Where does this code exist?  `viewDidLoad`?  `viewWillAppear`?  Somewhere else?

Comment: I have different versions of this code where I see nothing but a blue background and if I set an explit frame on left and right], I get the squares (red and green) that I set in the frame on top of blue background, but no stretching.

Comment: This code right now just lives in an example AppDelegate:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions.  I've tried it in viewDidLoad as well.

Comment: suggestion: if you can target iOS6+ use AutoLayout for this.

Answer (score 1):

You never set the initial frame of the 2 views.

This code is tested and working in a UIViewController

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    CGRect fullFrame = self.view.frame;

    // position left view
    CGRect leftFrame = fullFrame;
    leftFrame.size.width = leftFrame.size.width / 2;
    self.left = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:leftFrame];

    // position right view
    CGRect rightFrame = leftFrame;
    rightFrame.origin.x = rightFrame.size.width;
    self.right = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:rightFrame];

    [self.left setAutoresizingMask:(UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight)];
    [self.right setAutoresizingMask:(UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight)];

    [self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
    [self.left setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    [self.right setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];

    [self.left setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleToFill];
    [self.right setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleToFill];


    [self.view addSubview:self.left];
    [self.view addSubview:self.right];
    [self.view setAutoresizesSubviews:YES];
}
```

Comment: And if the parent view (self.view, e.g.) gets resized later, will the children get auto resized?

Comment: Yes, they will get resized.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set some initial frames of the subviews which you add to the main view. This should help:

```
self.left.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.window.frame.size.width/2, self.window.frame.size.height);
self.right.frame = CGRectMake(self.window.frame.size.width/2, 0 , self.window.frame.size.width/2, self.window.frame.size.height);
```